# Android HTML form 'done' button sofkeyboard

Tags: android, softkeys

I am opening a facebook login page in `WebView` when user select login field soft keyboard appears. I would like to have a done key button on the soft keyboard, how to do it?

I know we can add the done button by the following code attached with edit field

```
ediText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

But it is HTML form in `WebView` any clue how to do that?

Comment: This is a good question... it'd be even better if you wrote well.

Comment: This is good question, but I don't think you will be able to find a resolution, as at least you need to have access to the webpage, and since it's Facebook it won't work that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have no control over the website being shown in the WebView, you are unable to change the type of keyboard that is appearing.

My tests indicate that Android devices will show a "Next" button for every **<input type="text" />** or **<input type="password" />** field on a website and a "Go" or "Done" button for the last element on the page. If there were some html or css property that could be used to force a different type of keyboard, then you could enable JavaScript in your WebView and execute a JavaScript pseudo url to alter the facebook page's input elements;

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("javascript://getElement('signinbox').style.someCssClass='someKeyboardProperty';");
```

However as stated above, I am unaware of any html/css tag that specifies this. Hope this helps!